# What's a neater, more pythonic way to do the following enumeration?

Tags: python, enumeration

```
for row, instrument in enumerate(instruments):
    for col, value in enumerate(instrument):
         self.table.SetValue(row, col, value)
```

Comment: Looks neat and Pythonic enough to me ;-)

Comment: not connected you your question, but the variables instrument and instruments look too similar, which makes debugging harder. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: What don't you like?  What's wrong with it?  What optimization do you think is possible?

Comment: @bgbg: The article that you quoted does not mention a `thing` / `things` problem. What names would you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mentioned in the comments that this loop is a part of asynchronous function (in terms of twisted framework). In this case you don't want to block for a long time:

```
from twisted.internet import task

for i, row in enumerate(instruments):
    task.coiterate(self.table.SetValue(i, j, v) for j, v in enumerate(row))
```

Thus all rows are assigned in parallel.

NOTE:

- Watch out for late binding for `i` and `row`. Use `(lambda i=i, row=row: ...)()` in that case.
- `task.coiterate()` uses global object therefore there could be multiple table updates simultaneously (it might not be what you want).

---

Here's [@SilentGhost' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900195/whats-a-neater-more-pythonic-way-to-do-the-following-enumeration/1900202#1900202) (deleted):

> `self.table = instruments`
>
> Because that's what you seem to be
>   doing.

And the comment by @[Ben Hughes] I'm referring to:

> I need to explicity call SetValue (its
>   on a PyGridTableBase) for each value -
>   as this code is invoked via a twisted
>   deferred method - my brain is not much
>   good at looping/enumeration in a neat
>   way..... – Ben Hughes

Comment: As I write this comment, there are no comments by the questioner, neither on his question nor on any of the existing answers. I note in this context that SilentGhost has deleted his original answer :-). It would be a very good idea if the questioner updated his question with any relevant information.

Comment: @John Machin: I've included deleted answer & comment for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. SO really needs an alternative to deleting messages -- an "I wish I'd never written this" button :-) -- apart from problems like leaving other answers referring to thin air, I have noticed cases where an answer that acquired upvotes in the early hours of its life but was later shown to be incorrect should have its reputation points surrendered but the text left there because there are references to it in other answers.

Answer (score 4):

What you are calling `row` is not a row, it is a row index. `instrument` is a row. Apart from that:

If the only tool that you have is a `SetValue(row_index, column_index, value)` method *and that method does more than help replicate the structure of `instruments` laboriously*, and the `instruments` collection is as your code describes, then there is no better way. It is already much better than

```
#WARNING: BAD PRACTICE! DON'T USE THIS CODE!
for row_index in xrange(len(instruments)):
    instrument = instruments[row_index]
    for column_index in xrange(len(instrument)):
        self.table.SetValue(row_index, column_index, instrument[column_index])
```

or any perversion thereof.

Otherwise you may be interested in `import copy; self.table = copy.copy(instruments)` or even (as SilentGhost has suggested) `self.table = instruments`

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental question is not regarding this loop.

The fundamental questions are these:

1) Where does this `instruments` structure come from, and why do you need to reorganize it?

2) What is this `self.table` structure on which you're calling  `SetValue`?

3) What are you going to do with this `self.table` structure?

Until you answer these questions, your sample Python code has no context in which it can be evaluated.  It's just code.

Answer (score -3):

One option is using a list comprehension:

```
[self.table.setValue(row, col, value) 
    for row, instrument in enumerate(instruments) 
        for col, value in enumerate(instrument)]
```

Not sure if it is any neater or more pythonic... But it is another way of expressing the loop.

One could argue that the list comprehension is clearer, since the "action" part (setValue) is placed first/at the top. Instead of being buried inside the loop.

**EDIT:**

Yet another way, using a helper function and a generator expression:

```
def loop(iterator):
    for item in iterator: pass

loop(self.table.setValue(row, col, value) 
    for row, instrument in enumerate(instruments) 
        for col, value in enumerate(instrument))
```

The helper function can be the built-in any() if you know for certain that the loop body will never evaluate to True in a boolean context (any() will stop the iteration on the first True).

Comment: Do you think so? The statements are exactly the same, only ordered differently, and wrapped in []

Comment: That being said, I've never used a list comprehension in this way myself. It feels a bit weird to not have ``variable = [...]``, only the ``[...]`` without using the returned value.

Comment: It's certainly a good way of uselessly filling up a list with a whole series of None values and then throwing the list away.

Comment: Sure. To avoid that, use a generator expression

Comment: @codeape: After your edit, you are STILL abusing the syntax which is: `expression "for" ...` not `statement "for" ...`

Comment: self.table.setValue() is also an expression. Two attribute references and a call.

Comment: @John Machin: Note how the accepted answer is also "abusing" the generator expression syntax :-)

Comment: @codeape: Problem is that the "expression" returns None; it is being evaluated for its side effects. You're right about the accepted answer; I saw it mentioned `twisted`, shuddered and stopped reading ;-)